# Azure is not recognizing clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've created a SQL Server table on Microsoft Azure. I can create new items, but when I try to delete item `delete from Users where ID = 1` I get error:

> Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

Table is created by following syntax:

```
create table Users
(
    ID int primary key clustered not null identity,
    FirstName varchar(50) not null,
    LastName varchar(50) not null,
)
```

Users' ID is used as foreign key in other tables.

Comment: please post the actual table schema definition (the 'not null' is in wrong place...) All tables in Azure require a clustered index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Users' ID is used as foreign key in other tables.

These tables also need clustered indexes.

Comment: I had one table with many to many relationship and this table contained foreign keys only. Adding primary key to this table solved the issue. Thank you!